# Convert a given time to seconds in solaris

Tags: bash, shell, solaris

I have a time like 2013-04-29 08:17:58. And i need to convert it to seconds since epoch time.
No perl please and my OS is solaris. +%s does not work. nawk 'BEGIN{print srand()}' converts the current time to seconds but does not convert a given time to seconds.

Thanks

Comment: The above link demonstrates 3 different approaches: using C, perl and awk.

Comment: The above link describes how to convert current time to epoch time. I dont have to convert current time. I need to convert some other time which may be a date before a year or so

Comment: Your restraints are probably unrealistic.  Solaris does not allow %s as a date format specification.  If you absolutely have to use nothing but shell, then you will have to install GNU date which is available at [optcsw.org](http://www.opencsw.org)  This installs opensource binaries under /opt/csw.

Comment: [chris johnson's date code](http://cfajohnson.com/shell/?2013-09-16_date-functions.note)  Be warned this is a large library of inter- linked subroutines.  We considered it, but went with GNU date

Comment: Please those people who vote to close this question look closer. It is definitely NOT a duplicate of the above mentioned question. The OP is not asking about the current time but an arbitrary one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a shell function that doesn't require perl:

```
function d2ts
{
    typeset d=$(echo "$@" | tr -d ':- ' | sed 's/..$/.&/')
    typeset t=$(mktemp) || return -1
    typeset s=$(touch -t $d $t 2>&1) || { rm $t ; return -1 ; }
    [ -n "$s" ] && { rm $t ; return -1 ; }
    truss -f -v 'lstat,lstat64' ls -d $t 2>&1 | nawk '/mt =/ {printf "%d\n",$10}'
    rm $t
}
```

---

```
$ d2ts 2013-04-29 08:17:58           
1367216278
```

Note that the returned value depends on your timezone.

```
$ TZ=GMT d2ts 2013-04-29 08:17:58
1367223478
```

---

How it works:

- The first line converts the parameters to a format suitable for `touch` (here "2013-04-29
- 08:17:58" -> "201304290817.58" )
- The second line creates a temporary file
- The third line change the modification time of the just created file to the required value
- The fourth line aborts the function if setting the time failed, i.e. if the provided time is invalid
- The fifth line traces the `ls` command to get the file modification time and prints it as an integer
- The sixth line removes the temporary file

Comment: Wow, you don't have `stat`(1) either?

Comment: +1 still, but if your `touch` won't understand your date format, it's turtles all the way down.

Comment: Not until Solaris 11. `stat`(1) isn't POSIX.

Comment: That 'truss' magic is just what I was looking for! (Needed a way to get the epoch-time of a file/directory)

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ on UNIX, you can convert directly:

```
struct tm tm;
time_t t;

tm.tm_isdst = -1;
if (strptime("2013-04-29 08:17:58", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm) != NULL) {
    t = mktime(tm);
}
cout << "seconds since epoch: " << t;
```

See [Opengroup manpage `strptime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) for the example.

I admire the strace/touch niftyness and the creativity behind it. Though, well, just don't do this in a tight loop ...